# Turn geolcation in city name code doesn't seem to work

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, geolocation

I'm trying to get a geolocation and turn that into text. I got code to do that but it gives me an error. How can this error be solved?

The error: TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'geocoder.geocode')

The code:

```
var geocoder;

if (navigator.geolocation) {
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successFunction, errorFunction);
} 
//Get the latitude and the longitude;
 function successFunction(position) {
var lat = position.coords.latitude;
var lng = position.coords.longitude;
codeLatLng(lat, lng)
}

function errorFunction(){
alert("Geocoder failed");
}

function initialize() {
geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();



}

function codeLatLng(lat, lng) {

var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
geocoder.geocode({'location':latlng}, function(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
  console.log(results)
    if (results[1]) {
     //formatted address
     alert(results[0].formatted_address)
    //find country name
         for (var i=0; i<results[0].address_components.length; i++) {
        for (var b=0;b<results[0].address_components[i].types.length;b++) {

        //there are different types that might hold a city admin_area_lvl_1 usually does in come cases looking for sublocality type will be more appropriate
            if (results[0].address_components[i].types[b] == "administrative_area_level_1") {
                //this is the object you are looking for
                city= results[0].address_components[i];
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    //city data
    alert(city.short_name + " " + city.long_name)


    } else {
      alert("No results found");
    }
  } else {
    alert("Geocoder failed due to: " + status);
  }
});
}
```

Comment: If the error is on line which says `geocoder.geocode`, check to see if latlng variable is really assigned a latLng object.

Comment: I checked and this doesn't seem to be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

To [Reverse Geocode](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#ReverseGeocoding), the request structure contains `latLng`, not `location`

From the example in the documentation slightly modified (not tested):

```
 function codeLatLng(lat, lng) {
    // remove irrelevant code
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
```

Also, this is not correct, if you are going to use the first result (result[0]), you should check whether that existst (if results[0]  ... not if results[1]):

```
if (results[1]) {
 //formatted address
 alert(results[0].formatted_address)
```

Looking at [your jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gMszg/), you are not loading the API correctly. Please see the [documentation on the correct way(s) to load the API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#Loading_the_Maps_API)

Comment: Thank you for your answer :) I'm still getting the same error though. Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'geocode' of undefined

Comment: is your initialize function being called before you try to use the geocoder?

Comment: I checked, and this was indeed the case. However, now I get a different error: TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'geocoder.geocode')

Comment: I don't get any errors.  Maybe you need to post more code or a jsfiddle that exhibits the problem.

Comment: Does that jsfiddle exhibit the problem?

Comment: Yes, this jsfiddle exhibits the problem

Comment: I find that hard to believe, are you sure you checked the link you shared?  In Chrome, it doesn't display anything (not even the code), just an alert "Geocoder failed". Firefox pops up a request to share location, then nothing, IE just displays lots of errors in the jsfiddle code.